React native app jumps to the top for no apparent reason
I'm at my wits end with this one.
I have a chatbot app, in React native. And for some reason, it jumps to the top when send button is pressed and when bot message starts streaming. I have no idea what is causing this, but I believe it has something to do with the the ChatScreen view re-rendering for some reason.
Here is the ChatScreen.js code:
import "react-native-url-polyfill/auto"
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  Image,
  Keyboard,
  SafeAreaView,
} from "react-native";
import styles from "./Styles";
import { TypingAnimation } from "react-native-typing-animation";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const MessageItem = React.memo(({ message, navigation }) => {
  const renderMessageContent = useCallback((content, source) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={message.type === "user" ? styles.userMessage : styles.botMessage}>
          {content}
        </Text>
        {source && (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('PDFViewer', { 
              uri: source.pdfUrl, 
              page: source.page 
            })}
            style={styles.pdfLink}
          >
            <Text style={styles.pdfLinkText}>View source in PDF</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }, [message.type, navigation]);

  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.messageContainer,
        message.type === "user"
          ? [styles.userMessageContainer, { flexDirection: "row-reverse" }]
          : styles.botMessageContainer,
      ]}
    >
      <View style={styles.avatarContainer}>
        <Image
          source={
            message.type === "user"
              ? require("../assets/userProfilePicture2.png")
              : require("../assets/botPicture2.png")
          }
          style={styles.avatar}
        />
      </View>
      <View
        style={[
          message.type === "user" ? styles.userMessageBubble : styles.botMessageBubble,
        ]}
      >
        {renderMessageContent(message.content, message.source)}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
});

function ChatScreen({ messages, isLoading, sendMessage, isConnected }) {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleSendMessage = useCallback(() => {
    if (inputText.trim().length > 0 && isConnected) {
      Keyboard.dismiss();
      sendMessage(inputText);
      setInputText("");
    }
  }, [inputText, isConnected, sendMessage]);

  const handleInputChange = useCallback((text) => {
    setInputText(text);
  }, []);

  const renderBotTyping = () => (
    <View style={[styles.messageContainer, styles.botMessageContainer]}>
      <View style={styles.avatarContainer}>
        <Image
          source={require("../assets/botPicture2.png")}
          style={styles.avatar}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.botTypingBubble]}>
        <TypingAnimation
          dotColor="#ffffff"
          dotMargin={10}
          dotAmplitude={3}
          dotSpeed={0.15}
          dotRadius={3}
          dotX={25}
          dotY={-3}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollViewRef.current) {
      scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
    }
  }, [messages, isLoading]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={[styles.chatScreenContainer, { flex: 1 }]}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 80 : 0}
      >
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.chatArea}
          ref={scrollViewRef}
          contentContainerStyle={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}
          onContentSizeChange={() => scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
        >
          {messages.map((msg, index) => (
            <MessageItem key={index} message={msg} navigation={navigation} />
          ))}
          {isLoading && renderBotTyping()}
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.inputArea}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="What do you need?"
            value={inputText}
            onChangeText={handleInputChange}
            onSubmitEditing={handleSendMessage}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity 
            style={[styles.sendButton, !isConnected && styles.disabledSendButton]} 
            onPress={handleSendMessage}
            disabled={!isConnected}
          >
            <Text style={[styles.sendButtonText, !isConnected && styles.disabledSendButtonText]}>Send</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default React.memo(ChatScreen);

I first thought this was something to do with the auto scroll view, so I removed any auto scrolling component, but it made no difference at all.
